# How get non common values from 2 different column of 2 Different table

Tags: sql

I wrote one query from where i able to achieved below outcome. But due to lack of understanding in SQL not sure is there any function or way that I could achieve Expected outcome shown in 2nd table.

Current result  from my queries with listagg function:

| id | val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 666 | 1151 | 1151 |
| 667 | 1151 | 2120 |
| 668 | 2120 | 2120 |
| 669 | 2120 | (null) |
| 670 | 1116,2120 | 1116,2120,1151 |

where:

| id | val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 670 | 1116,2120 | 1116,2120,1151 |

from this  last row: picking only not matching value and showing
as below outcome for 670 id.

Expected outcome:

| id | val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 667 | 1151 | 2120 |
| 669 | 2120 | (null) |
| 670 | (null) | 1151 |

I'm not sql developer so  get confuse how could i acheive this

my query :

```
select   zone1.Id,zone1.VAL1,zone1.Org,zone2.VAL1,zone2.staff_ids
        from (   SELECT ta1.Id,  ta1.VAL1,ta1.P_DATE,ta1.Org 
                     FROM vw_summary ta1 LEFT JOIN tbl_staff t3 ON t3.staff_id in(ta1.Org) ) zone1
         left  join
               ( SELECT        tb1.advice_id, tb1.VAL1,
         listagg(t1.ID, ',') within group (order by tb1.VAL1) as staff_ids
                    FROM vw_advice tb1 
                    LEFT JOIN tbl_issue t1 ON tb1.VAL1 = t1.VAL1                 
                    GROUP BY  tb1.advice_id, tb1.VAL1
                  )  zone2 on zone1.VAL1=zone2. VAL1
        where P_DATE LIKE '%-22%'   
        GROUP by  zone1.Id,zone1.VAL1,zone1.Org,zone2.VAL1,zone2.staff_ids
        order by  zone1.VAL1 asc;
```

Comment: You should also add the logic which takes us from the sample table to the expected output.

Comment: Sample data like 1, 2, 3, and a, b, c, are so much easier to read than 177201116, 87091667, 87091667, 87091669 etc. Make it easy to assist you!

Comment: You'd probably better do it in your original query. Can you share original setup here?

Comment: shared lemme know in case anything needed

Answer (score 0):

if I am not wrong you want get these three records in id base
you can use this query
select val1,val2 from table_name where id = 87091667|| id=87091669 || id=87091670

Comment: Appreciate your response but i want whole  line , if val2 and val2 have any conflicts. if both identical then I don't want to show in result